# how to create a data validation menu in VBA for different cells in different sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a message box with a data validation list that will populate across a certain cell.

ie:
pick a number:
1
2
3

user picks #1 and cell A on worksheet B is populated with value

I thought of going around something like this:

```
Range("A2").Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
Formula1:="Orange,Apple,Mango,Pear,Peach"
```

but thats just for one sheet. i need it for different sheets on different cells. any ideas ? thanks !

edit: from a reply to a comment that was below that i thought was important.

@ChristoferWeber I want there to be a message box that pops up with a drop down menu. and within that drop down menu there's options like: A,B, and C. and when the user chooses A. then the value of A gets inputted to cell A3 for example.

Comment: Do you want "a message box with a data validation list" inside of a cell? Or a separate message box, and a data validation list in the cell? Or a userform with the message and list, that populate the current sheet? If what you have works, just specify which sheet it is, and then add the other sheets with their respective cells?

Comment: Qualify the range - with other words, tell VBA/Excel where the range `A2` is, eg: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").Validation...`

Comment: @ChristoferWeber I want there to be a message box that pops up with a drop down menu. and within that drop down menu there's options like: A,B, and C. and when the user chooses A. then the value of A gets inputted to cell A3 for example.

Comment: Will the list in the drop down (combobox) always be the same options, but with different results depending on the sheet?